# How to make delete duplicates faster?

Tags: mysql, performance, query-performance

On a mysql table with about 1.7M rows, I tried to delete duplicates posts:

```
delete a FROM comment a
  INNER JOIN comment a2
     WHERE a.id < a2.id
     AND   a.body = a2.body;
```

The result was:

```
  Query OK, 35071 rows affected (5 hours 36 min 48.79 sec)
```

The table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `comment` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `author_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `body` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `post_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `published` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `cid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `id_postid_idx` (`id`,`post_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1774682 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

This happened on my almost idle workstation with `Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4790 CPU @ 3.60GHz`. 
I'm wondering if there are some tricks to make this delete operation faster?

Comment: What is `SHOW CREATE TABLE comment` - edit question and include. If its an innodb table what `innodb_buffer_pool_size/innodb_log_file_size` do you have set?

Comment: @danblack the schema added. `innodb_buffer_pool_size = 8G ` and `innodb_log_file_size = 256M`

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm is "Order(N^2)".  If you have a million rows, it will take about a trillion comparisions!  (Actually closer to N*N/2.)

I assume you want to run this again later?  Or you want to avoid inserting duplicates?  In either case, the following will speed things up greatly.

```
ALTER TABLE `comment` ADD COLUMN hash BINARY(20);
UPDATE `comment` SET hash = UNHEX(SHA1(body));
ALTER TABLE `comment` ADD UNIQUE(hash);  -- (see discussion below)
```

When `INSERTing`, include `hash` with a value of `UNHEX(SHA1(body))`.  If the hash is a dup, then `body` is extremely likely to be a dup, and the `INSERT` will suitably fail.

`INDEX` versus `UNIQUE`:

- `INDEX` gives you a much faster way to do the dup-elimination:  check `hash` instead of `body`.
- `UNIQUE` prevents future insertion of dups.

So, let's do it in two phases:

1. Add `INDEX(hash)` (not `UNIQUE(hash)`)
2. Do the dedupping -- With an `INDEX(hash)`, the `DELETE` is Order(N) -- a million tests, not a trillion.
3. Change to UNIQUE:  `DROP INDEX` + `ADD UNIQUE`. -- Now future `INSERTs` will balk; so add suitable code to deal with such.  Consider `INSERT IGNORE`.

All of that will take minutes, not hours.  And you won't have to do any of it again.

(With a newer version of MySQL, you could use `GENERATED ALWAYS` to avoid some of the code.)

**One shot**

To do the delete once and do it without modifying the table:

```
CREATE TABLE t (
        id INT NOT NULL,
        hash BINARY(20),
    PRIMARY KEY(id),
    INDEX(hash) ) ENGINE=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO t (id, hash)
    SELECT id, UNHEX(SHA1(body))
        FROM `comment`;

DELETE FROM `comment`
       JOIN  t AS t1  ON t1.id = comment.id
       JOIN  t AS t2  ON t2.hash = t1.hash
                     AND t2.id < t1.id;

DROP TABLE t;
```

Caveat:  I have not tested this code.  Recommend you test it separately, perhaps with a subset of the data.

Comment: Well this is definitely helpful as a database design tip, my actual problem is to clean up a legacy table. I don't have the luxury to change the table structure. So hopeing to find a delete trick which is not of Order(N^2).

Comment: Here is the correct `DELETE` for mysql: stackoverflow.com/a/56691931/10855747. Nevertheless, after the operation on a table with 1.7M rows, I still have 2K duplicates, down from original 55K dups. So this method does not work as expected.  Any thought about it?

Comment: @Milkyway - Any chance those were triples?

Comment: Could be. But after second round of running the queries,  I still have those remaining number of duplicates.

Comment: I tried on other tables and this method works. Please modify the delete as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/56691931/10855747 and I'll accept your answer. Thanks a lot for bearing with me.